# Create a mix of horizontal and vertical text in a footer

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, vertical

I'm trying to make a footer in the bottom corners that has a mix of a horizontal page number, with a colored background, plus some vertical text containing fixed text (for example the title of the report) as well as the current section name, like in the image below (bottom right corner of an example page). I can't find anywhere how to do this and would appreciate any assistance! An MWE is included.

[image: Bottom right corner of an odd page]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[O]{
\normalfont\sffamily\small\bfseries\scshape
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[blue] ($(current page.south east)+(-1.5in,0in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(-.5in,.75in)$);
    \node[anchor=center, text=white] at ($(current page.south east)+(-1in,.5in)$) {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\fancyfoot[E]{
\normalfont\sffamily\small\bfseries\scshape
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[blue] ($(current page.south west)+(1.5in,0in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south west)+(0.5in,.75in)$);
    \node[anchor=center, text=white] at ($(current page.south west)+(1in,.5in)$) {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Title e.g., `Report Template'
\section{Overview}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What you try to obtain is not  fully clear. Must the rectangle be laid at the bottom roghtcorner of the sheet  or at the bottom of the page frame?

Comment: I would use the everypage package, with or without tikz.

Comment: Sorry, for the rectangle it is at the bottom of the page bleeding off the bottom. But really the shape isn't so important as I'm concerned with placing the vertical text (with section name) on top of what the MWE generates, approximately 0.5in inward from the side of the page (in the margin), and ~1in from the bottom. That's the component I can't get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using package `scrlayer` instead `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer}[2016/10/03]
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{}
\renewcommand\sectionmarkformat{}

\newkomafont{outertext}{\normalfont\normalcolor\sffamily\small\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  oddpage,
  background,
  align=br,
  hoffset=\paperwidth-.5in,
  voffset=\paperheight,
  width=1in,
  height=1in,
  mode=picture,
  contents={%
    \putLL{\textcolor{blue}{\rule{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}}}%
    \put(\LenToUnit{.5\layerwidth},\LenToUnit{.75\layerheight})
      {\raisebox{-\height}{\makebox[0pt]{\pagemark}}}%
  }
]{pagenumber.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=pagenumber.odd,
  evenpage,
  align=lb,
  hoffset=.5in
]{pagenumber.even}

\makeatletter
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=pagenumber.odd,
  contents=\putUR{\makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \rotatebox[origin=tr]{-90}{\usekomafont{outertext}%
      \MakeUppercase{\@title}%
      \ifstr{\rightmark}{}
            {\ifstr{\rightbotmark}{}{}{\ \textbar\ \rightbotmark}}
            {\ \textbar{}\ \rightmark}%
 }\enskip}}
]{text.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=pagenumber.even,
  contents=\putUL{\makebox[0pt][l]{\enskip
    \rotatebox[origin=tl]{90}{\usekomafont{outertext}%
      \MakeUppercase{\@title}%
      \ifstr{\leftmark}{}{}{\ \textbar\ \leftmark}%
  }}}
]{text.even}
\makeatother

\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{mystyle}{%
  pagenumber.odd,pagenumber.even,%
  text.odd,text.even%
}
\DeclarePageStyleAlias{plain}{mystyle}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\title{Report Title}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! That's a really nice solution and just what I'm looking for.